# Expresso Store: If member, fill in blank shipping\billing details automatically?

Tags: expresso-store, fields, checkout

Client wants the check out pages to automatically populate the shipping\billing details if they're a member and have already done it before.

Does Expresso have any sort of functionality to accommodate this?

Comment: I have this working but it doesn't seem to work for custom fields. This is the code that I am using. I am mapping the custom member field to the custom field in store but it's not pulling in the info. The other ones I set up worked but they weren't custom. Any thoughts? <div class="control-group {if error:order_custom2}error{/if}"> <label class="control-label" for="order_custom2">Cell Phone</label> <div class="controls"> {field:order_custom2} {error:order_custom2} </div> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store does have the ability to pre-populate the checkout fields. Basically you either need to create custom member fields or if you are using Zoo Visitor you would need to create custom channel fields that will hold the users address details. Once you have done that you will need to go Store > Settings > Order Fields and map the form input fields to the custom fields that you have just created as seen in the picture below. ([Docs Link](https://exp-resso.com/docs/settings_order_fields.html)) [image]

Once you have done that in your template you have 2 options in your template to pre-populate the fields:

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 <label for="billing_first_name">First Name</label>
 {field:billing_first_name}
{/ezp:store:checkout}
```

or

```
{exp:store:checkout}
 <label for="billing_first_name">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="billing_first_name" value="{billing_first_name} class="input" />
{/ezp:store:checkout}
```

Documentation on the checkout fields can be found [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#billing_details).